# Object BoxUpdate is missing some infos

Tags: box-api

The BoxUpdate object doesn't give all the fields the API send when get_updates is requested. Especially the 'files' array (why is it an array btw ?).

So in my updates section, I can tell who did what and when but not on which file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The get_updates API in the V1 Box API (http://developers.box.net/w/page/22926051/ApiFunction_get_updates)  provides a slimmed down list of the file and folder fields (including the IDs).   If you want the full information for the file or folder(s) that were updated, you need to call the appropriate API.

The reason that get_updates returns an array is b/c many files or folders may get touched between times you call the get_updates API.   The API lets you send a begin and end timestamp, and get a list of updates, so it has to be an array.